# Can't connect to Sunspot server in Ubuntu server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I followed the steps in https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot/wiki/Adding-Sunspot-search-to-Rails-in-5-minutes-or-less to install & set up Sunspot search in Rails in a Mac OS and it is ok.
In a Ubuntu server, there's connection refused error.
When I run

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

and the proccess starts. The file `sunspot-solr-development.pid` is created in `/tmp/pids`.
But when I try to reindex

```
rake sunspot:reindex
...
rake aborted!
Connection refused - connect(2)
```

I tried to run the commands with `sudo` and gave permission `777` to the project files, but there's still error.
Rails 3.0.8.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `netstat -anp | grep <name of the server>` show?

Answer (score 2):

Try `rake sunspot:solr:run` -- this runs it in the foreground which will expose any errors happening at startup.

FWIW, I don't recommend using the bundled Solr instance in production environments, if that's what you're doing. Better to use Ubuntu's package manager or install one of the distributions provided by Solr.

Comment: I followed
https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot/wiki/Configure-Solr-on-Ubuntu,-the-quickest-way
and it's now ok. First, I was using openjdk, but still got errors. Than i switched to java-jdk and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure soLr is running on the correct port: 8983 for production etc

```
ubuntu@host:~/rails-project$ cat config/sunspot.yml 
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO

bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production
```